# Merge two YAML files using yq

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, yq

Using YQ, I can merge 2 Kubernetes Helm chart yaml value files together using:

```
yq '. *= load("values-prod.yaml")' ../web/values.yaml
```

However, with values-prod.yaml, I need the contents to be dynamically generated at runtime.

I'm trying:

```
yq '. *= load("<(helm template -f values-prod.yaml -s templates/web.yaml . | yq .spec.source.helm.values)")' ../web/values.yaml

Error: Failed to load <(helm template -f values-prod.yaml -s templates/web.yaml . | yq .spec.source.helm.values): open <(helm template -f values-prod.yaml -s templates/web.yaml . | yq .spec.source.helm.values): no such file or directory
```

I've tried multiple variations of quotations with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `helm template` and other commands with multiple `-f` options, and Helm will merge them for you.  You also might see if you can use Helm's native templating support; can you avoid using `yq` entirely?

Comment: hi @DavidMaze, this would display the generated manifest rather than displaying the merge values file. I was hoping to see the merged values file.

Answer (score 0):

`load` is an operator of `yq`. It accepts a file name as a parameter.
You cannot use process substitution here as this is shell syntax
(the error is generated by `yq`, not by your shell).
You need to create the dynamic content outside `yq` and pass it to `yq`.

Maybe you can just swap the two inputs:

```bash
yq '. *= load("../web/values.yaml")' <(helm template -f values-prod.yaml -s templates/web.yaml . | yq .spec.source.helm.values)
```

I can't test this code, but I hope the idea leads you to the solution.